# setting a dynamic height to a div based on screen space available

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, height

what i need to achieve is the following:

a webpage for smartphone that contains a series of divs with heights, paddings, margins, etc..  and one particular div at the bottom that should be as high as the (window.innerHeight minus all the other divs' heights before him) so that the javascript can stick a fixed height to it (which has to be dynamic because i don't know the device screen height) and i can set via CSS overflow:auto and make it scrollable.

the js i started using is the following:

```
        (function() {
        function resize(delta) {

            var heights = window.innerHeight;
            jQuery('.dynamic-height').css('height', (heights - delta) + "px");
        }

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod touch);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) {
            resize(20);

        } else {
            resize(0);

        }
    })();
```

you can ignore the if/else statement.

here is a very simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/k56wj/

the div that has to have the dynamic height is div.dynamic-height (violet background).

thank you so much for your help, this would be a life saver! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k56wj/5/)

```
        (function() {
            function resize() {
                total = 0;
                jQuery('.cont div').each(function(){
                    total += parseInt($(this).css('margin-top').split('px')[0])+parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom').split('px')[0])+$(this).height()

                });
                var heights = window.innerHeight;
                var dy_height = heights-total

                jQuery('.dynamic-height').css('height', dy_height + "px");
            }
resize()

        })();
```